# How to show progress bar in Python CGI + Jinja? - accessing dynamic variable?

Tags: progress-bar, cgi, jinja2

I'm trying to add a progress bar to my Python/Jinja2 webpage.

Using an JS progress bar for unknown length/constant animation is easy, but since I know the % of completion of my script, I'm hopping to display the actual rate.

I tried searching this topic, but found nothing about how to actually displaying an actual progress bar using python CGI or Jinja.

The part blocking me is that I have no idea of how to update the constantly changing variable (progress %) to Jinja and update the progress bar on the webpage.

I thought of using `{%block%}` as a wrapper for the progress bar, and re-render this part in python script every time the % increases. This theoretically should work, but logically doesn't seem to be the right method, because this entire block (instead of just the %) would be constantly refreshing for tens of times.

It makes more sense to me if the variable in Python can be dynamically updated in the rendered HTML page, or that if Jinja can access the cgi.FieldStorage posted from Python, but I couldn't find any ways of doing either of these...

[edit]
I tried using block but didn't work out.

```
// base.html
  {%block body%}
  {%endblock%}
// block.html
  {%extends "base.html"%}
  {%block body%}
    <div class="progressbar"></div>
    {{super()}}
  {%endblock%}
//python
for 1 in 10
    template = env.get_template('block.html')
    print template.render(var)
```

The page would load, but the progress bar repeatedly appends to the previous one for 10 times..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out CGI doesn't natively support this due to limitation.
my resolution:
print progress in div => delete div => repeat.

Comment: I guess that works! But why not use a simple microframework like Flask instead of just a CGI?